# Use boolean method to determine output

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I am trying to get the user to input three numbers for each of the three rows. Then add up the values of columns 1, 2, and 3 separately. If the value of all 3 columns adds up to 1 independently then it should use a boolean method to print out "yes". I don't know how to get the boolean method to work though and none of the examples around here are specific enough to help me. Any thoughts on what I can do to get it to work properly?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MarkovMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initializing all arrays
        double[] FirstRow = new double[3];
        double[] SecRow = new double[3];
        double[] ThirdRow = new double[3];
        double[] ColSum = new double[3];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Getting input from user
        System.out.print("Enter first Row: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < FirstRow.length; i++){
            FirstRow[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter Second Row: ");
        for(int j = 0; j < SecRow.length; j++){
            SecRow[j] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter Third Row: ");
        for(int k = 0; k < ThirdRow.length; k++){
            ThirdRow[k] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        // Summing all columns
        ColSum[0] = FirstRow[0] + SecRow[0] + ThirdRow[0];
        ColSum[1] = FirstRow[1] + SecRow[1] + ThirdRow[1];
        ColSum[2] = FirstRow[2] + SecRow[2] + ThirdRow[2];

        boolean isMarkovMatrix; 

        if(isMarkovMatrix = true)
            System.out.println("Matrix is a Markov Matrix");
    }//End of main

    public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(ColSum double) {
        if(ColSum[0] = 1 && ColSum[1] = 1 && ColSum[2] = 1)
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `isMarkovMatrix` and then you are planning to use it in `if(isMarkovMatrix = true)`. Guess you need to study your code properly to avoid such things

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if(isMarkovMatrix = true)` will always be evaluated as true because you are assigning  `true` to `isMarkovMatrix`. Instead, you should do:

```
if(isMarkovMatrix == true)
```

Or even better, just

```
if(isMarkovMatrix)
```

**Edit:** in your `isMarkovMatrix` method signature, you need to place the data type first and then the variable.

In addition `=` is an **assignment operator**, `==` is the right **comparison operator** you want to use in this method.

```
public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(double[] ColSum) {
        if (ColSum[0] == 1 && ColSum[1] == 1 && ColSum[2] == 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Btw: do you really want to compare double with integer? Why not directly use integers?

Comment: Thank you. It's also stating that in public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(ColSum double) there is an error. It is saying its expecting ; after ColSum and double. Isn't ColSum the input and the double the type of input?

Comment: All of the inputs are going to be decimals, like .45 .74 .82. If these all add up to 1 then its good, otherwise it's not a Markov Matrix.

Comment: @Requin okay, then you might want to have a level of precision for tolerance. for example 0.0000001